# Window Leak, no flashing?

Tags: windows, leak

I recently had new windows installed and have since had a significant leak from the top of two of our downstairs windows. The contractor had come back to check and stated that the windows were installed and sealed properly.

I just popped off what I could on the siding, and it looks to me as if both there is no flashing tape, and the side jambs are overlapping the top jamb which I believe should be the other way around to prevent water from seeping in, correct?

I apologize for the low quality picture, I have just frustratingly taken it in the dark.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A properly installed window, by definition, does not leak!

Comment: And by "jamb", I think you mean the J-channel, which belongs to the siding.

Comment: Looks like an absolute hack job. The right thing to do isn't always the easy thing to do and apparently that contractor couldn't care less about doing things right.

Comment: Your picture showing the water soaking into the wood is pretty conclusive evidence that it's not installed and sealed properly. Was this evidence available when the contractor came back? Where did the water come from? Precipitation? Sprinklers? Somebody testing the window with a hose? That image should light a fire under the contractor, as he should see the growing cost implications of neglecting the problem.

Comment: Have you made final payment to the contractor? If not, let him know you're withholding that until this is fixed properly. If so, that's a lesson learned for you.